# VMSS scale up with booting executable after launch

Tags: azure, deployment, automation, azure-service-fabric

I have VM scale set for my Azure ServiceFabric Application deployed in Azure. I need to run RabbitMQ server on each virtual machine in my VM scale set when it starts (especially actual when I am going to scale up my cluster and new VM is going to be created). In other words I want make queue run automatically. Are there any possibilities to do the next steps after VM has been launched:

- Check if RabbitMQ is already installed.
- Download and install if not from specified URL.
- If it has been installed just run it.

I guess this issue can be solved with virtual machine scale set Automation Script, but I am not sure. Any ideas and suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using a VM custom script extension. An extension runs on every new VM when a scale set is deployed or when it scales out.
Your extension could do the checks, install and run, and perhaps create a service so RabbitMQ runs if the VM is rebooted etc.
The following articles provide more details on deploying apps with scale sets: 
[Deploy your application on virtual machine scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app)
[How are Applications deployed on VM Scale Sets?](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/deploying-applications-in-azure-vm-scale-sets/)

Comment: Wow! Cool! Thank you for sharing me this. I will have a look through it and elaborate this approach. Thanks a lot. Just give me some time :)